# Microphone doesn't work during CallKit calls using an iPhone 6S with iOS 13.3

Tags: ios, voip, callkit

After updating to iOS 13.3, when the app is in foreground, the microphone doesn't work during a CallKit call. When, instead, the call arrives while the app is in background or when the phone is locked, it works.

This happens only with iPhone 6S. Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Does your app have permission to use the microphone?

Comment: @AdamPro13, YES,  I double checked.